# How to build NativeScript Vue app compliant with Google Play 64-bit requirement?

Tags: android, build, google-play-console, nativescript-vue

I created my project with the command from the guide:

```
vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template <project-name>
```

and I build release APKs with the following command:

```
tns build android --bundle --release --key-store-path ./my_key.jsk --key-store-password *** --key-store-alias key1 --key-store-alias-password ***
```

But when I upload the APKs to Google Play Console, I get this error:

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

With a link to this page: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit.

How can I build release APKs compatible with the new requirements?

Others say I'm supposed to add `ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'` to my Gradle script. Is that what I should do? And where exactly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `App_Resources/Android/app.gradle` update your defaultConfig to include:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

So your app.gradle should end up looking something like:

```
android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "<applicationId>"
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
  }  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Per this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4330), I am using only these filters:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'
```

`x86` and `x86_64` are uncommon architectures and my app did not need to support them.

Comment: `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a` are common 64-bit architectures that satisfy the 64-bit requirement. Per the linked issue in GitHub, I still had issues when including the `x86` and `x86_64` which I explained are uncommon and not needed for all apps depending on the level of support.

Comment: x86 (and thus x86_64) is required for some wearable devices. Removing it off the list doesn't solve the problem, does it? Although, I agree that removing it satisfies Google requirement since the other two happily provide both 32bit and 64bit versions.